# Opening multiple excel files using Python

Tags: python, excel

I have multiple excel files in a directory and would like to open those files at a time to perform write operations (To, for example, write "Hi" in the first row of all the excel files). Is there any way to do so in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need more control you can do something like this (solution from a person called Jay, not sure if he is the original author. http://www.python-excel.org/)

```
import xlwt

x=1
y=2
z=3

list1=[2.34,4.346,4.234]

book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")

sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Sheet 1")

sheet1.write(0, 0, "Display")
sheet1.write(1, 0, "Dominance")
sheet1.write(2, 0, "Test")

sheet1.write(0, 1, x)
sheet1.write(1, 1, y)
sheet1.write(2, 1, z)

sheet1.write(4, 0, "Stimulus Time")
sheet1.write(4, 1, "Reaction Time")

i=4

for n in list1:
    i = i+1
    sheet1.write(i, 0, n)



book.save("trial.xls")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import csv    
with open('A.csv','w') as a, open ('B.csv', 'w') as b:
    a_reader = csv.reader(a)
    b_reader = csv.reader(b) 
    ...
```

Now you can iterate through the both files.

The python module [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) can be of help also, it allows to iterate over lines of multiple files passed as arguments.